# Android WebView Not Loading Correctly

Tags: android, webview

I'm having a few issues regarding the WebViewClient on Android.
The site works **perfectly** on any mobile browser. Including the ChromeViewClient that I have set for debugging purposes.

And the website that I am loading does not have any issues or errors when using any other mobile browser. Using Chrome's inspector and selecting a device, using as mentioned the native Android browser and also tested on an iOS WebView Component to make sure.

The WebViewClient renders "parts" of the website. Images on one page and not the other, buttons that can not be clicked, a slider that does not work,  etc. The website that I am loading is very JavaScript and HTML5 intensive. I am completely out of ideas of how to debug this issue further, are there certain JavaScript libraries that the WebViewClient can't load properly? Is there any other method you would recommend I implement while trying to debug this issue? Or am I missing some really small thing that will make me hit my head against the table?

These are the JS files we are using on the website:

- `bootstrap.min.js`;
- `jquery.min.js`;
- `swiper.jquery.min.js`;
- `slideout.min.js`;
- `owl.carousel.min.js`.

Code for the WebView:

```java
this.webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        firstLoad = true;
        return true;
    }

    // when the page is finished loading
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){}

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Could Not load. " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
        alertDialog.setMessage(description);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                return;
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
});

webview.loadUrl("mywebsite.com");
```

Comment: Android 4.4 and above use the Chromium engine, but before that it was the WebKit engine. Do you know if your problem is version specific?

Comment: @RupertRawnsley I just tested it on 4.0.3 and the WebView seems to have the same issue.

Comment: I would strip out everything except the enabling of javascript and then check logcat for any unexpected errors, for instance a javascript parsing error. If that fails, post a jsfiddle version of the page so we can try it locally. Without that it's hard to speculate; there is nothing obvious in the code except that the shouldOverrideUrlLoading is a bit unusual.

Comment: @RupertRawnsley so I am about to blow your mind with my noob mistake. I didn't setDomStorageEnabled(true); to use session storage.

Comment: @RupertRawnsley * Session Storage * thats a decent few hours of stress I won't get back. Thanks for your response and help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it working by `setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

You need to set this when using local storage.

Comment: Ugh, classic Android WebView! The default behaviour of the iOS equivalent is much more forgiving.

Comment: I am facing the same issue while running my page on android 4.4. Using setDomStorageEnabled did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: I did the all below to make it work `webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.userAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U;` Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17"
`