# Why did my WebView didn't load the owl-carousel content?

Tags: android, webview, carousel, owl-carousel

I have a webview that will visit a website, the problem here is that 
[it didn't load the entire website content
][1]

Then I tried to use Chrome to access the website, and [it loads all the websites content][2](even though a bit messed up since it viewed in mobile).

When I tried to see the content of the missing things (things that didn't showed up in my WebView), I learned it didn't load the content that use owl-carousel,

Is there a way to let my WebView load the owl-carousel content?

P.s I have activated the javascript too

Here's the codes I create that I think lead to the problem

**My Webview settings**

```java
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

And here's my Webview procedure

```java
 public class myWebclient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed(); 
        }


    }
```

**Progress Update**

I have tried using [AdvancedWebview](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) like what [Sudheesh R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6630837/sudheesh-r) said, but it's still like previous condition nothing changed, it still don't load the owl-carousel content

**Update #2**
I̶ ̶t̶r̶i̶e̶d̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶f̶r̶i̶e̶n̶d̶ ̶W̶e̶b̶V̶i̶e̶w̶ ̶a̶p̶p̶,̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶k̶s̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶e̶d̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶p̶p̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶I̶ ̶d̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶k̶n̶o̶w̶ ̶w̶h̶y̶,̶ ̶I̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶u̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶I̶ ̶f̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶.

Alright, I have compared his code with mine, nothing seems comes to light...

**Update 3**
The only resource I found is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072352/android-webview-not-loading-correctly), but as you see in my code above, I have set the Dom Storage to become enabled... Any help really appreciated

**Update 4**
Alright, I found out that there's a Jquery method in the website that I haven't initialize yet from my Logcat

So I initialize it but keeping it empty

```java
@JavascriptInterface
    public void getxId(){ 
    } 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lPNX.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS6tV.png
```

Comment: try with this webview library https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView.

Comment: Do I have to download the library first and after that adding it at the same folder of my project? #newbie

Comment: just follow the instructions in the github page. Everyone once was a newbie when they're starting. No issues bro.

Comment: Alright let me try this library

Comment: I think I will use the library as my second option since I need to reconfigure everything again with it...

Comment: ok as you wish.

Comment: If you just want to load your webview in the app, maybe you can try chrome custom tabs, it is much simpler to implement and loads the webpage properly  https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: "The WebView is good solution if you are hosting your own content inside your app. If your app directs people to URLs outside your domain"

Since it will direct to a web that will used in my office system, I will stay with WebView

Comment: I've tried using Advanced webview, but nothing changed, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Updated with what I have tried